# Don't know why i get React Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs

When i use the function in funkFiltriranje inside filtriranje everything works fine:

```
export default class Vraboteni extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filtriranje = this.filtriranje.bind(this);
    this.funkFiltriranje = this.filtriranje.bind(this);
}   
//i'm calling filtriranje(e) by <Form onSubmit={this.filtriranje}>
filtriranje(e){

    e.preventDefault();
 var arr1 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'gadipol'},{embg: 'tri'}];
    var arr2 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'bljat'}];

         var arr = arr1.filter(function(n) {
     for(var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++){
         if(n.embg === arr2[i].embg){
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 });
console.log(arr);
}
 }
```

But when i code it like this it gets an error:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Vraboteni.filtriranje (Vraboteni.js:72)

```
funkFiltriranje(e,arr1,arr2){

     var arr = arr1.filter(function(n) {
         for(var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++){
             if(n.embg === arr2[i].embg){
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     });
     return arr;
}

filtriranje(e){

    e.preventDefault();
 var arr1 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'gadipol'},{embg: 'tri'}];
    var arr2 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'bljat'}];

    var arr3 = this.funkFiltriranje(e,arr1,arr2);

}
```

Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: You're getting into an infinite loop...

Comment: It would be great if you can share complete component code

Comment: I know that but why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
  onSubmit={this.filtriranje} //this gets called on every render without user interaction
```

To

```
 onSubmit ={e => this.filtriranje(e)} //this gets called only when you click on a button or user interaction
```

This way onSubmit only triggers when there is user interaction like when you click on submit button for eg.

Comment: That and I took off the binding in the constructor and it works now thanks

Comment: This is completely wrong, both sample of code given in this answer do the exact same thing. Your function in the first example is not called unless the event is fired

Answer (score 0):

```
funkFiltriranje = (e,arr1,arr2) => {

     var arr = arr1.filter(function(n) {
         for(var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++){
             if(n.embg === arr2[i].embg){
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     });
     return arr;
}

filtriranje = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    var arr1 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'gadipol'},{embg: 'tri'}];
    var arr2 = [{embg: 'gad'},{embg: 'bljat'}];
    var arr3 = this.funkFiltriranje(e,arr1,arr2);

}
```